# I am getting SSL connection error: Unable to get private key

Tags: mysql, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

- CA (this is an intermediate certificate) Private KEY `ECDSA`
- SERVER-CERT derived from CA - Private KEY `ECDSA`
- CLIENT-CERT derived from CA - Private KEY `ECDSA`

I am using ECDSA private key (client certificate) and a certificate to make a SSL connection to MYSQL database. Key is passphrase less (not encrypted)

To decrypt the private key:

```
openssl ec -in db_key1.pem -out db_key.pem
```

User is given REQUIRE SSL:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'ssluser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret' REQUIRE SSL;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

When I am connecting with the following command:

```
mysql --verbose  --ssl-ca=root.pem  --ssl-cert=db.pem --ssl-key=db_key.pem --host database --port 3306 -u ssluser -p
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: Unable to get private key
```

My initial guess was the proper permission is not set for these files, and then I add these files to `mysql:mysql`. But I am still getting the same error.

MYSQL is only supporting RSA or does it support ECDSA. And most of the documentation is based on RSA.

In [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connection-protocols-ciphers.html), I can see the following ciphers are supported.

```
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
AES128-GCM-SHA256
DH-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
AES256-GCM-SHA384
DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
AES128-SHA256
DH-DSS-AES128-SHA256
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
AES256-SHA256
DH-DSS-AES256-SHA256
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
AES128-SHA
DH-DSS-AES128-SHA
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
AES256-SHA
DH-DSS-AES256-SHA
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DH-RSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256
DH-RSA-AES256-SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
AES128-SHA
DH-DSS-AES128-SHA
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
AES256-SHA
DH-DSS-AES256-SHA
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
DH-RSA-AES128-SHA
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA
DH-RSA-AES256-SHA
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA
DES-CBC3-SHA
```

And I tried to set the `--ssl-cipher='ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256'` in my mysql command

Answer (score -1):

Turned out this is a Bug/limitation in MySQL server.

Comment: ... and what _is_ the bug/limitation, exactly?